# OleDbDataAdapter fill datatable

Tags: vb.net, oledbdataadapter

A question about filling an `OleDbDataAdapter`.

I have:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(myQuery), myConnection)
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim dtDonnees As DataTable = New DataTable()
da.Fill(dtDonnees)
```

Filling takes too much time.
For 20 lines it takes 20 seconds.
And for 130 000 it takes a little more (but not 130 000 sec).
But 20 seconds is too much anyway.

Why does it take so much time?

---

Question part 2: can I skip fill?

I mean, after filling the datatable, I do a for each row of datatable and cast into an entities:

```
Dim returnList As New List(Of myObject)(dtDonnees.Rows.Count)
For Each rowDonnee As DataRow In dtDonnees.Rows
   returnList.Add(New myObject(rowDonnee))'set every data of the row into my new object
Next
```

Can I pass each row of `OleDbDataAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try, you could skip the DataAdapter fill with this method (assuming that the DataTable is not needed). Not sure that you could gain much in performance.

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection) 
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read()
   returnList.Add(New myObject(reader))
end while
```

of course, in the constructor of your obiect, you should read the data and set the internal state of your object

```
Public Class myObject

   Dim myData As String
   ' other internal var to keep state of this object instance

   Public Sub New(ByVal reader as OleDbDataReader)
       myData = reader.GetString(0)
       ' read and initialize other internal data.
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: yeah thats what I got. but the constructor get a datarow so I set LocalVar = tryPars(myRow("columnX")).

Comment: I think the reader is able to do the same. but why you said that will not gain speed?

Comment: In your example we can say that we have two loops. One to fill the DataSet and one to construct your objects. Using a DataReader we remove one loop and the caching in memory of the row inside the datatable. Unfortunately, the datareader has no easy way to convert its current data line in a DataRow, so if you want to use this method you need to add a new constructor. About speed. I can't say if the datareader speeds things up, you need to benchmark. The cost of building and initializing an instance could be more relevant than the cost for a reader.read/adapter.fill

Comment: I will bench it with my 130000 data. maybe that will help not so much, it can be worst.

Comment: @forX I'm curious, let me know.

Comment: I test with 20 and 10000, no so much better, like 1 to 5sec. but its 1 to 5 no matter how many lines. if I have time, I will test with 130000lines. for now , I have other priorities.